# Redirect all requests to HTTPS, except for one subdirectory

Tags: nginx, redirect, http, https, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to move from self-signed certificates to Let's Encrypt certificates on my nginx webserver.

Currently, I redirect all requests to `http/80` to `https/443`, which uses a self signed certificate I created a while ago.

Now - from what I understand Let's Encrypt makes a request to port 80 (as I am using the `webroot` option of `certbot`). These requests are redirected, which renders the certificate generation unsuccessful.

I tried to achieve this with the following server block, listening at port 80:

```
server {
        listen  80;     
        server_name     sub.domain.tld;
        server_tokens   off;


        location /.well-known {
                root /var/www/letsencrypt;
        }

        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
```

But requests to `/.well-known` are redirected to `https/443` anyways.

How can I redirect all requests from `http/80` to `https/443`, except the requests to `/.well-known/`?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the `webroot` of `certbot` option requires plain http.

Comment: How did you check redirect? I guess your browser respects HSTS headers for you domain, but let's encrypt bot would ignore it. Check with `wget`/`curl`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
server {
    listen  80;     
    server_name     sub.domain.tld;
    server_tokens   off;

    root /var/www/letsencrypt;

    location /.well-known {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Since there was no `try_files` entry in your virtual server, it didn't know what to do with requests coming to `/.well-known`.

Comment: `location` without `try_files` just sends file from `root` directory.

Comment: weird, I have the exact same situation and I dont use `try_files` and it works perfectly fine for me. In fact I have the exact same config as stated in the question. Only difference is `location /.well-known/` instead of `location /.well-known` (note the trailing slash). So maybe thats where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but needed a slightly different solution.

Here's what my server block looked like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

It turns out this is a "pitfall" NGINX dubs the [*Incorrect `return` context*](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#incorrect-return-context).

> The return directive applies only inside the topmost context it’s defined in. In this example:
>
> ```
> server {
>    location /a/ {
>        try_files test.html =404;
>    }
>
>    return 301 http://example.org;
> }
> ```
>
> A request to `/a/test.html` will return a 301. To make this work as expected wrap the second block inside a `location /`:
>
> ```
> server {
>    location /a/ {
>        try_files test.html =404;
>    }
>
>    location / {
>        return 301 http://example.org;
>    }
> }
> ```

I understand what they mean, but the phrasing makes it a little confusing. I would instead describe the behavior as

> The `return` directive takes precedence over all `location` blocks defined in the same context.

Wrapping the `return` in a `location /` block, as suggested, solved the issue.